# Possibilities for Unbounded Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(s_n)_1^\infty$ be an unbounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Some possibilities for $s_n$ are:

1. $\lim s_n = +\infty$
2. $\lim s_n = -\infty$
3. $s_n$ oscillates between large and negatively large numbers. Ex. $s_n = (-1)^n * n$

Are these three the only possibilities for $s_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. We need only the existence of a subsequence that tends to either plus or minus infinity. So a couple of examples are:

$$s_n:=\begin{cases}\log k&\text{if}\ n=10^k,\\-\frac1n&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}\\
s_n:=-n(1-(-1)^n).
$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, a sequence in a metric space is unbounded if and only if it has an unbounded subsequence. It would be a good exercise to prove that, and constructing a few examples should give you an idea of unbounded sequences that don't fall into those three categories.

Comment: Thanks Math1000. This may be off-topic, but I am confused by your usage of "In general". I read http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207461/in-general-do-mathematicians-use-this-phrase-oppositely-from-everyone-els but the answer does not seem to be definitive. In this case, is your following statement (involving metric space) always true? If so, you can omit "In general", right? Or do you mean there are exceptions but it is mostly true?

Comment: It's a valid question, not off-topic. I meant the former. For another example, we might say: "$2\leqslant|2|$, and in general, $a\leqslant|a|$ for a real number $a$"